# Is there any way to reset the external library on Pycharm?

Tags: python, settings, external

I am learning Python for the first time.

Due to my curiosity, I changed some code in the external libraries. But I forgot what I have modified.

So is there any way to reset the external libraries? I am using python 3.7 interpreter on Pycharm.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: both python 3.7 and pycharm?

Comment: No, the external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just back up your python project file, reset Pycharm to factory defaults and then upload the project back to Pycharm.